# Inheritance in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, inheritance

Has anyone worked with React using inheritance on large scale projects?

With the experience you got from it, would you start another project applying the same pattern or you'd rather go with traditional composition?

Asking this because one of our Team Leads is pushing the inheritance even though the most of the developers are against it.

Thanks in advance,
Have a great day.

Comment: Ask him if he can show you a react project with `class inheritance` and update us.

Comment: Hey, i'm your Team Leader, please close this question :) I'm joking, composition is the only way with react!

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html - just show him this link, its a great explanation of why composition is the way to go and its from the official docs

Comment: "At Facebook, we use React in thousands of components, and we haven’t found any use cases where we would recommend creating component inheritance hierarchies."

Comment: Thanks lads, during our research we've found answers like the ones you provided. I was hoping to find someone that actually tried this abomination and can provide some feedback :D